# I have a list of names, I need to create a list that pairs these names in the format "1. Name1 2. Name2", "1. Name1 2. Name3"

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image: My attempt]

So from the picture, I've managed to do this for a single name 'Hank' as Number 1, I need this list to iterate through and include all names as '1.' with the other names as the corresponding '2.' , is there a function I could write that would do this for any number of initial names?

I can create each list of names separately but I wanted to know if theres a function that could produce all combinations in one go

Answer (score 4):

### Combine Names From a List

[image]

```
=LET(data,A1:A3,f,"1. ",s,"  2. ",
DROP(REDUCE("",data,LAMBDA(rr,r,
    VSTACK(rr,f&r&s&FILTER(data,data<>r)))),1))
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try using the following formula as well, it doesn't require <kbd>LAMBDA( )</kbd> helper functions.

Using <kbd>LET( )</kbd> , <kbd>TOROW( )</kbd> & <kbd>TOCOL( )</kbd> with a single argument in <kbd>IFS( )</kbd>.

---

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>C1</kbd>

```
=LET(
     a, A1:A9,
     b, TOROW(a),
     TOCOL(
        IFS(
            a <> b,
            "1. " & a &
                " 2. " & b
        ),
        3
    )
)
```

---

[image]

Comment: Brilliant. I wasn't aware of this `TOCOL/TOROW` business and you made me finally fully understand `IFS`. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I found a non-lambda solution:

`=SORT(TOCOL(IF(TOROW(A1:A9)<>A1:A9,"1. "&TOROW(A1:A9)&" 2. "&A1:A9,NA()),3))`

Or shorter as suggested by Mayukh:
`=TOCOL(IF(TOROW(A1:A9)<>A1:A9,"1. "&A1:A9&" 2. "&TOROW(A1:A9),NA()),3)`

Combining the range with it's transposed equivalent `TOROW(range)&range` or `TRANSPOSE(range)&range` will produce an 2D array of all combinations, including the combination of it's own value.

To workaround that we use `IF` (or `IFS`) and check for the value in the range not being equal to the transposed value.

The if it isn't equal we return the value of the range and the value of the transposed range, else we declare an error value `NA`, of when using IFS if the condition isn't met it throws an error value.

If we wrap this in `TOCOL()` the 2D array is flattened  to a 1D array and the second argument of TOCOL being `2` or `3` filters out error values (the duplicates).

Comment: Make it this way, so you will need one function less: `=TOCOL(IF(TOROW(A1:A9)<>A1:A9,"1. "&A1:A9&" 2. "&TOROW(A1:A9),NA()),3)` let me know if i am wrong.

Comment: Cool stuff! That does the sorting indeed

Comment: Barely relevant, but we are forgetting about `IFS` in its simplest form i.e. `=IF(x,y,NA())` is actually the same as `=IFS(x,y)` which is 4 chars shorter. Luckily, we have Mayukh to remind us.

Comment: @VBasic2008 Sir, I have asked P.b. to remove `SORT()` and haven't asked to use `IFS()` intentionally otherwise my answer and his would become similar, apart using the `LET()`